# Efficient way to merge objects

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I have a somewhat large list of "stations," say 350,000 or so.  These stations came from five different sources and they each have particular pieces of information.  For example they each have at least one of five different types of identifier.  The goal is to merge equal stations (stations are equal if they have a matching identifier).

Example:  If stationA has identifierA: 01234, identifierB: NULL, and identifierC: KAKW, and stationB has identiferA: NULL, identifierB: USA00012, and identifierC: KAKW, I want to merge these together as a newstation with identifierA: 01234, identifierB: USA00012, and identifierC: KAKW.

Right now I have all the stations in one large vector.  I am moving one station at a time into a new vectior by 1) pushing it back if it doesn't match any station already in the vector, or 2) merging it if there is a match.

This is taking WAY too much time.  Theoretically speaking is there an efficient algorithm or concept that I can use to speed up this process?  The last time I did it it took almost 3 days.

Comment: I tried googling "equivalence sets" and so on, thinking you hadn't. Because this is a well researched and known problem. E.g., it occurs in Fortran compilers, which have to deal with silly equivalence definitions. Alas, I didn't find it! Still, it's not so difficult. Use a hash table of encountered identifiers, associated with logical stations. For each station loop over all identifiers, find any corresponding logical stations via the hash table. Merge them if more than one, or create new one if there are none yet. I think this will do all relevant merges, but think about it. Perhaps google?

Comment: The C++ standard library's main hash table implementations are `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`. I think two to three minutes is a reasonable upper bound on the process, on a typical PC.

Comment: While I appreciate the power of Google, it's difficult to do a google search on what took me four paragraphs to explain.  Hence why I came here.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 copies of your data, with each copy sorted by a different identifier.

Then choose one, iterate, and look for matches in the sorted containers. Build the combined object and save that to the "processed" vector.

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* like it should be a hash-table-y type problem, but maybe it isn't, because there's more than one way for two stations to be equivalent.

I'd suggest something similar to Amit's answer, if you can spare the memory. Just have 5 `std::map` containers of identifiers acting as indices into the main container (like a database), and do your searching that way. There's a bit of up-front work getting the identifiers into the sorted containers, but it would probably end up being faster.

If you don't care which identifier matches which, or if your identifier data sets don't intersect, you could just use a single container with all five identifiers munged together (possibly hashed, but excluding NULLs, presumably), and search on that.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does a pass over the stations, effectively generating a bitmask of the identifiers that station has.  It flips those bits to create a bitmask that another station with only the missing identifiers would have, and if such a station is already known merges with it, adding the merged-from station to a list to be erased later.  Otherwise, it adds the unmatched station to the list of stations with its specific bitmask, so it can be found quickly later.  (Very little testing done.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Station
{
    int idn_map() const { return 16 * bool(ia_[0]) +
                                  8 * bool(ib_[0]) +
                                  4 * bool(ic_[0]) +
                                  2 * bool(id_[0]) +
                                      bool(ie_[0]); }
    void merge(const Station& rhs)
    {
        if (ia_.empty()) ia_ = rhs.ia_;
        if (ib_.empty()) ib_ = rhs.ib_;
        if (ic_.empty()) ic_ = rhs.ic_;
        if (id_.empty()) id_ = rhs.id_;
        if (ie_.empty()) ie_ = rhs.ie_;
    }

    std::string ia_, ib_, ic_, id_, ie_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Station& s)
{
    return os << s.ia_ << ':' << s.ib_ << ':' << s.ic_ << ':' << s.id_ << ':' << s.ie_;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Station> stations = {
        { "s0a", "",    "s0c", "",    "s0e" },
        { "",    "",    "s1c", "s1d", "s1e" },
        { "",    "s2b", "",    "s2d", "" },
        { "s3a", "s3b", "s3c", "s3d", "" },
        { "s4a", "s4b", "",    "",    "" }
    };

    std::vector<Station*> unmatched[32];
    std::vector<Station*> to_erase;
    for (Station& s : stations)
    {
        int idn_map = s.idn_map();
        if (unmatched[idn_map ^ 31].empty())
            unmatched[idn_map].push_back(&s);
        else
        {
            // merge from current element so to_erase kept sorted
            // for fast compact/erase later...
            Station* p_merge_to = unmatched[idn_map ^ 31].back();
            p_merge_to->merge(s);
            to_erase.push_back(&s);
            unmatched[idn_map ^ 31].pop_back();
        }
    }
    for (const auto& p : to_erase)
        std::cout << "will remove element at " << p << '\n';
    // now compact over the deferred erasures...
    auto erase_it = to_erase.begin();
    auto to = stations.begin();
    for (auto from = to; from != stations.end(); ++from)
        if (erase_it != to_erase.end() && *erase_it == &*from)
            ++erase_it;
        else
            *to++ = *from;
    stations.erase(to, stations.end());

    std::cout << "results:\n";
    for (const auto& station : stations)
        std::cout << station << '\n'; 
}
```

Code available/runnable [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/183648c8cabcf0bd).

(Been a couple edits while I corrected loop logic, changed from using a set to vector to improve performance)